# How to set CodeIgniter to ignore Wordpress folder?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, routes

I built a website with CodeIgniter last year www.example.com, and client wanted Wordpress Blog last week. I built the blog and uploaded to www.example.com/blog

Now when I click any link on wordpress it gives error as below :/

http://www.example.com/blog/category/one-last-category/

> **An Error Was Encountered**
>
> Unable to
>   load your default controller. Please
>   make sure the controller specified in
>   your Routes.php file is valid.

How can I set Codeigniter to ignore Wordpress folder?

Appreciate helps!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to do this with an .htaccess file (assuming your web server supports it.)  For example, in the DocumentRoot of my Codeigniter site I have an .htaccess file which contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This allows me to still access static files and the CI user guide.  In your case the RewriteCond would be something like:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|blog)
```

Comment: yes, I found this at a forum with a huge luck! :) thanks anyway!